# How can I get the logical reads for a SQL statement in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking at Autotrace output in SQL Developer, and I can see Physical IOs but not Logical IOs. This is one of those searches that in Google returns a lot of information about Oracle Tuning, but nothing that directly seems to answer the question.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Use the `autotrace` option in SQL*Plus (don't know if SQL Developer supports that): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2698680

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is "consistent gets" + "db block gets", which together sum up all Loigical IOs.

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_difference_consistent_db_block_gets_physical_reads.htm